# Definition of parallel vectors in Tom Apostol's calculus, vol. $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

The definition in section $12.3$ says that two vectors $A$ and $B$ are called parallel if $B = cA$, for some $c \ne 0$.

I understand that makes sense when both of the vectors $A$ and $B$ are having $0$ origin (e.g. $A = (a_1, a_2)$, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are coordinates in 2D space representing the vector tip), but what happens with vectors which are equivalent to those 0-origin vectors, but their start and end points are not at $(0, 0)$ (considering only 2D case for now)?

For example I don't know how to fit vector translation up into that definition, because if I construct vector $B$ such that it has the same $x$ coordinates as in $A$, and just add $5$ to the $y$ coordinates of $A$, there is no single $c$ which would make $B = cA$.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to geometrically think of the vector as having a tip from the origin, then it's okay, the tip can be placed anywhere arbitrarily. But the coordinates of the vector should be interpreted as displacement from the starting point. Then there will be no contradiction anymore.

Comment: @AndrewZhang yes, but my question is exactly if I should try to make that definition compatible with completely arbitrary vectors, or I need to fix the starting point for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apostol's notation and terminology, he distinguishes between *vectors* ($n$-tuples of real numbers) denoted by single symbols and *geometric vectors* (with a head and a tail) denoted $\vec{PQ}$ if it has tail $P$ and head $Q$. He then points out that if we map the geometric vector $\vec{PQ}$ to the vector $Q - P$, then *equivalent* geometric vectors go are mapped to *equal* vectors (equation 12.1). The definition is about vectors, but you could convert it to a definition about geometric vectors by using this map.